# what is padding for PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC

Tags: java, aes, bouncycastle, jasypt

What is padding for PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC (Bouncy Castle)

Sorry for tiny information, let me elaborate more background of the question.
There have two systems. One is java (**A**) and another is PHP (**B**). Now we have one requirement to send string/text from system A to B. The content of string/text is encrypt by AES using `jasypt`. But I cannot decrypt it using `mcrypt`. I suspect it may due to A and B are using different parameters of AES so I try to find out how system A encrypt string/text.
The information what I found are shown as below except **padding**,

jasypt ( java simple encryption )/PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC

cipher: AES

length: 128 bit

encryption mode: CBC

JCE providers : Bouncy Castle

Salt : FixedStringSaltGenerator

Iterations: 2

Padding : **????**

***Thank in advance!***

Comment: That is so vague. Can you elaborate?

Comment: http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html for all of padding list accordingly

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on the actual `Cipher` instance you use to encrypt, thus your question doesn't make much sense (as @Buhake Sindi points out).

In any case, it would not be unusual to use PKCS#5, as in

```
Cipher.getInstance( "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" )
```

The point is: *You* decide the padding mode (the provider must implement it of course).

Have a look at the [BouncyCastle Specifications](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) - it should be clear from section 4.2 which padding modes can be used with which ciphers. Again, the default is PKCS#5/#7.

Cheers,

Comment: I think I found out answer from oracle. For PBE（Password-Based Encryption）is use PKCS5.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppA

Comment: There's nothing in that link/anchor combo related to padding, you know? To reiterate: Most crypto implementations will default to PKCS#5/7, but you can choose otherwise using the `Cipher.getInstance( "algorithm/mode/padding" )` transformation.

Comment: Good for you :-) I posted that link above yesterday with some comments as well.